# Highcharts: Dynamically update dataLabels in synchronization with setData

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to update dataLabels in synchronization with setData.

[image]

When I call setData, I want update dataLabels like 1, 2, 3, ... 100, ... 1000. Anything is OK about the interval of numbers.

```
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
    series: [{data: [1]}]
});    
chart.series[0].setData([1000], true, {duration: 3000});
```

This is live demo. https://jsfiddle.net/Shinohara/hqsbcoum/11/

Please anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the `dataLabel` text in interval function:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var newValue = 1000,
        actualValue = chart.series[0].points[0].y,
        dataLabelInterval,
        counter = 1,
        step = (newValue - actualValue) / 10;

    chart.series[0].setData([newValue], true, {
        duration: 3000
    });

    chart.series[0].points[0].dataLabel.attr({
        text: actualValue
    });

    dataLabelInterval = setInterval(function() {
        counter++;
        chart.series[0].points[0].dataLabel.attr({
            text: actualValue += step
        });

        if (counter > 10) {
            clearInterval(dataLabelInterval);
        }
    }, 300);
}, 2000);
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/01zfoyud/